# Airflow initdb command fails after linking with postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, airflow

I am trying to connect Airflow with a Postgresql DB.

When in `airflow.cfg` I change the `sql_alchemy_conn = spostgresql+psycopg2://127.0.0.1:5432/airflow`, where `airflow` is the name of my DB which is installed on the same machine.

After updating the config file, I run `airflow initdb` and get the following error which I cannot understand:

```
  File "/some_path/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 232, in load
    "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" % (self.group, name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:spostgresql.psycopg2
```

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/AbPSrqH0kb4) on the web, which seems to "solve" this problem, but the solution was not clear to me at all.

Can someone tell me what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have a typo in your sqlalchemy connection string (`s` at the beginning of `postgres`). Try changing:

```
spostgresql+psycopg2://127.0.0.1:5432/airflow
```

to

```
postgresql+psycopg2://127.0.0.1:5432/airflow
```